# s3:listallbuckets works on aws console but not on cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Context: I have configured right aws-access-key and aws-secret-key
I can see buckets contents on aws-console but on aws-cli

Here's my boto3 code

```
import boto3

# Enter the name of your S3 bucket here
bucket_name = 'xxxx'

# Enter the name of the region where your S3 bucket is located
region_name = 'ap-southeast-1'

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region_name)

# List all the objects in the bucket
objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

# Print the names of all the objects in the bucket
for object in objects['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'])
```

I have `"s3:List*"` under my AWS-policy. What am I missing?

I am trying list all buckets using aws-cli it works using aws-console but not cli. I have rechecked my aws-secret/acess key, everything is right.

EDIT: aws-cli throws error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong? Any errors?

Comment: Hey @Marcin listed the error message

Comment: Where and how do you setup the aws credentails and how do you run the code? On ec2 instance, lambda, ecs container, ...? Sadly your question lacks details and it is unclear.

Comment: I have had aws creds setup on awscli, running the code on my endpoint not on cloud.

Idk if this makes it more confusing, sorry aws noobie.

Comment: You have mentioned three access methods in your question: **AWS Console** (works okay), **AWS CLI** (doesn't work) and you have also shown us some **Python code** (but you haven't told us whether it is working). Please Edit your question and show us the **AWS CLI command** that is generating the error, the **policies on the IAM User** that you are using and tell us **why** you included the Python code in the Question.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with python code, both CLI command ```aws s3 ls``` and the python code it self is throwing the error.

I have included the python code, incase I might have missed something in boto3,

Comment: Please Edit your question and include the policies on the IAM User that you believe is granting the appropriate permission.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of error happens if you have multiple AWS profiles in your PC and you are using the wrong profile to make a call a call to AWS
Make sure the default profile is the profile that has access to the AWS account.

You can also use `aws s3 ls --PROFILE_NAME` to get the list of buckets if you have multiple profiles

Run `aws sts get-caller identity` to get the current caller identity

Comment: What command are you running to retrieve the buckets?

Comment: I have only one AWS_profile on endpoint, using command ```aws configure```

Comment: I have updated the answer, run aws sts get caller identity,l let see the current profile

Comment: So I have verified
Account and ARN seems to be same thing from aws-console
```
{
    "UserId": "xx",
    "Account": "xx",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [ListBuckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html):

> Returns a list of all buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request. To use this operation, you must have the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission.

The wording is a bit confusing, but:

- `ListBuckets` returns a list of the **names of S3 buckets** in your AWS Account
- `ListObjects` returns a list of **objects in a particular S3 bucket**

Your Python code is calling `list_objects()`.

The AWS CLI error is saying `ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`, which suggests that you are trying to obtain a list of buckets, rather than a list of objects.

Comment: The thing is regardless of anything I have ```"s3:List*"``` under permission of policy.

Shouldn't that fix access denied?